# Alternative to Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

I've built an application (using Silverlight 4) which has been quite successful and is being used by a number of our clients.  We are planning for a new round of changes to the application, but we're concerned about the future of Silverlight and are pondering alternative approaches.  Here are the general requirements for our application -- we chose Silverlight specifically because it allows us to do all of these things:

- Must run on Windows and Mac
- Must allow for auto-updating when new features are added
- - Must allow for communication back to the server, but also allow network access on the user's LAN.

The last item is the kicker:  our application is used to communicate with a specific proprietary device. Sometimes that device is accessed "in the cloud" which is accomplished via RIA services back to our servers; but, in some cases the device exists on the user's LAN, so we're able to run out-of-browser and communicate with the device via a private LAN IP address.

Is there an alternative approach for this scenario *in the Microsoft stack of technologies*?  Or technologies using other approaches?

I'm concerned that Microsoft's roadmap for replacing Silverlight with HTML5 will not provide a mechanism for communicating on a user's LAN.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that Silverlight is your best option right now.  It's a mature product, and obviously does what you want it to do.  Silverlight will be supported by Microsoft for at least 10 years, so there's really no need to be worried right now about its future.  I really wouldn't be looking to swap to anything else if I were you.  Your other options are:

- WinForms (mature, but won't run on Mac, and is not being advanced any further)
- WPF (mature, but won't run on Mac, and is on the way out)
- ASP.NET/HTML (gives you reach, but is more difficult to develop for, and you won't be able to communicate with the device), and
- Metro (which is Windows 8 only, immature, and won't be out 'til later this year).

Really, Silverlight is your best option right now, and probably will be for quite some time yet.

Comment: +1: Good to see a sensible answer and not the usual doomsaying. Like so many technologies *Silverlight still has a place* until something better comes along (which it hasn't just yet).

Comment: How is the status  now?  I see in windows 10 edge does not work anymore for silverlight application. What would be the optimum direction for migration from  silverlight application to other platform?

Comment: It is quite ironic how silverlight is on its way out and WPF is still in today :).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check Blazor ( www.blazor.net ). Might be the only good web-alternative ;-)